# Post into Confluence table using REST API

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

Found many examples on simple API queries but nothing close to what i want.

I have my space key and page ID, this is my table
[image: table]

How can i append hyperlinks, and attach a file in cell 3 for each build using REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the page :  add `expand=body.storage` as a query parameter to get the body.storage.value which holds the html tags.
 Then parse the get response to edit the specific value in the 's then when updating the page update the body.storage.value withing your json like in the example: https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/REST/latest-server/#content-update